# Verificar valor da sessão do PHP?

Tags: php

Olá tenho um formulário cria uma sessão de usuário e de senha, que cria uma sessão de acordo com as informações enviadas pelo formulário e, no index.php, ele verifica se a sessão está "setada".

**PHP:**

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['senha'])) {
   header("Location: login.php"); 
   exit();
}
```

Esse código funciona super bem, mas eu quero que ele apenas verifique um valor  determinado, por exemplo se a `$_SESSION['senha']` for igual a `123`, caso seja, ele redirecione para login.php, caso contrário ele continue no index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para funcionar como você deseja, você simplesmente tem que validar se a `$_SESSION['senha']` esta "setada" e é igual a "123".

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['senha']) and $_SESSION['senha'] == '123') {
   header("Location: login.php");
   exit();
}
```